# jQuery multiple id sets multiple patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, sure this is really simple, but I'm new to Java / jQuery so all help knowledge is greatly appreciated!

I have three sets of information, but i want each set to behave the same way, when I check a box, I want a certain div to appear, then disappear when the checkbox is unchecked...

Started with this, and it works...

```
 //Set 1 #mod_1 toggles #sec_mod_1..
     $('#sec_mod_1').change(function() {
        $('#mod_1').toggle(this.checked);
     }).change();
 //Set 2
     $('#sec_mod_2').change(function() {
         $('#mod_2').toggle(this.checked);
     }).change();
 //Set 3
     $('#sec_mod_3').change(function() {
         $('#mod_3').toggle(this.checked);
     }).change();
```

Now this is a little long winded, and I know there has to be a shorter way... Thinking something like this...

```
     $('[id^="sec_mod_"]').change(function() {
         $('[id^="mod_"]').toggle(this.checked);
     }).change();
```

However, I don't know how to make this function for each separate set, was thinking the "this" keyword...?

Like I said all help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: what i need to do is adjust the #sec_mod_ (the action), while simultaneously adjusting the #mod_ (the trigger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple class selector:

```
$('.trigger').change(function() {
     var $checkbox = $(this);
     var id = $checkbox.attr('id'); // eg. sec_mod_1
     var numb = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1); // eg. 1

     $('#mod_' + numb).toggle(this.checked); // toggle #mod_1
 }).change();
```

Add `trigger` as the class to the elements that needs this functionality.

**Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/qc02z57b/)**

Comment: Wouldn't I need three separate class identifiers one for each set??

Comment: I recommend (and upvoted) this solution, classes are actually a better way to handle your use case and will help you abstract more of your code

Comment: @Simon you can get the id number and then show the correct mod div

Comment: Like i asked, wouldn't I then need three separate .trigger classes, one for each set, which would just be the same as what I have??

Comment: No because you get the right set by getting the id of the checkbox and so show the correct div `#mod_`

Comment: "you can get the id number and then show the correct mod div"....
Isn't that what I am doing anyway??
I was just looking for a shorter, more flexible solution rather than adding
    $('#sec_mod_1').change(function() {
        $('#mod_1').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();
one of these blocks for each set....

Comment: Well with my solution you have one function to do all of your toggling

Comment: @Mivaweb thank you got it! Thank you for your help!! Appreciate it greatly!

Comment: One more question, would I be better using a class on the "action" also?
Or, does that not make any difference, because this method is still using the "id" as an identifier for the trigger, right?

Comment: You mean for the`mod_` div element? No because then it would be hard to know which div you need, now you can get the right one using the id

Comment: That's what I thought, the id is the identifier for the target div... Great, thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use use the same markup with a handler like

```js
$('input[id^="sec_mod_"]').change(function() {
  console.log('d')
  $('#mode_' + this.id.replace('sec_mod_', '')).toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sec_mod_1" type="checkbox" />
<div id="mode_1">1</div>
<input id="sec_mod_2" type="checkbox" />
<div id="mode_2">2</div>
<input id="sec_mod_3" type="checkbox" />
<div id="mode_3">3</div>
```

Or if you can change the markup

```js
$('.sec_mod').change(function() {
  $($(this).data('target')).toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sec_mod_1" class="sec_mod" type="checkbox" data-target="#mode_1" />
<div id="mode_1">1</div>
<input id="sec_mod_2" class="sec_mod" type="checkbox" data-target="#mode_2" />
<div id="mode_2">2</div>
<input id="sec_mod_3" class="sec_mod" type="checkbox" data-target="#mode_3" />
<div id="mode_3">3</div>
```

Comment: @Simon can you edit the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hwbf1em7/1/) to recreate your problem

Comment: Got the first one you posted working, didn't see the "mode" which should have been "mod".....
Thank you for your help, really do appreciate the headache relief! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```
$('#mode_' + this.id.replace('sec_mod_', ''), this).toggle(this.checked);
```

Comment: that would take care of the #mod, what do I do about the #sec_mod?